How to study Hanzi deck in other directions
I downloaded the Most_Common_3000_Chinese_Hanzi_Characters deck. I'm not an expert, but it seems to have many fields and is set to show a few of them on the front, and a few of them on the back. Though this setting works for me, I'd like to in parallel, study the same deck in other directions, so with different fields on the front/back. How would I get that to work?
